# splitting text into many columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I have the following dataframe, and i want to split the column `activities` into other columns spliting the text by "," into my dataframe

```
id  activities
 1  541,589,235,45
 2  213,213
 3  458,88,999,150,360
```

I am using `df= df['activities'].str.split(',',5,expand=True)`

The dataframe shown is a subset from my real dataframe, in my dataframe i dont know how many activities they can be (in this case are 5 but in my dataset i dont know, so i need to change the 5 by "n" activities). And also if i perform that code I loose the `id` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. Once you split, you can either

- assign `id` back, or
- `concat` the two pieces

```
i = df.activities.str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('activity_')
i

  activity_0 activity_1 activity_2 activity_3 activity_4
0        541        589        235         45       None
1        213        213       None       None       None
2        458         88        999        150        360


j = i.assign(id=df['id'])   # assign id back
```

---

```
j = pd.concat([df[['id']], i], 1)   # concat the two pieces
```

---

```
j

   id activity_0 activity_1 activity_2 activity_3 activity_4
0   1        541        589        235         45       None
1   2        213        213       None       None       None
2   3        458         88        999        150        360
```

Comment: thank you that works, but why the last `i = pd.concat([df[['id']], i], 1)` ? If you already put back the id's with `i['id'] = df['id']`

Comment: @LucasDresl Alternative. Both either assign OR concat. Not both :-)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `apply(pd.Series)` here

```
df.set_index('id').activities.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('activities_').reset_index()
Out[479]: 
   id activities_0 activities_1 activities_2 activities_3 activities_4
0   1          541          589          235           45          NaN
1   2          213          213          NaN          NaN          NaN
2   3          458           88          999          150          360
```